# Heroku Force Enable TLS 1.1

Tags: heroku

Our clients were suddenly unable to connect to our backend on Heroku since August 2nd. They all use a Windows 7 or Windows 10 cash register device.

Apparently the cash register software that implemented our API doesn't support TLS1.2. And we didn't receive any notification from Heroku that legacy versions of TLS would be EOL.

We have solutions in progress (migrating to AWS or the 3rd party implementing TLS1.2), but they will take some time and my boss would love to have it solved by today.

Is there a possibility to force TLS1.0/1.1 via the Heroku CLI?